# Outlook for Mac suddenly not syncing

Tags: macbook-pro, email, ms-office

I have been using Microsoft Outlook on my Mac for more than a year without issues. I have a few accounts synced and never had any trouble. Out of the blue, Outlook does not fetch one of my gmail account emails. I never changed anything on Outlook and I do receive the emails normally on my phone and gmail web interface. Also receiving them fine on Mail.app. I have tried restarting Outlook but still the same issue. I don't get it at all. This is not an exchange account by the way so quotas shouldn't matter. Any ideas ?

(I have also disabled focused mailbox by the way)

Comment: have you removed and re-added the account? (which is the app-level equivalent of "have you rebooted the computer?";-)

Comment: That's a good point, I haven't tried this one, i'll give it a go.

Comment: I tried it and still not working. It is very interesting that I received a copy of the security alert on my recovery account on my other email account which is connected to Outlook as well and the email came in just fine. Now for the buggy email account that I deleted and re-added I got the security alert email on the web interface, but again not showing up on Outlook once again. This is very weird. Wonder whether it's some sort of local quota (even though it makes no sense).

Comment: It is not you, it is them. I have Microsoft email account that was constantly asking me to log in. Few days later it stopped doing that

Comment: I ended up going back to mail.app cause this is super annoying. I prefer the outlook interface but damn it's so inconsistent.